How to map IdeaVim Command + Shift + m to ]m?
I try below mapping but it doesn't jump to method.
nnoremap <D-M> ]m

How to do it in IdeaVim?

<D-m> is just Command+m. To get Command+Shift+m, you need to use <D-S-m>
